# How to set/access data object correctly using React with a Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, use-state

I’m having problems storing and accessing data with a `useState` hook in React after it is retrieved from a Firebase database. The problem seems to be stemming from the fact that not all users have all values in the `playerData` data packet – in this case, if the player has the ‘pioneer’ achievement, they can create a settlement, if not, they can only set their profile name (and in turn have an undefined `settlementName` within `playerData`). It works fine if the account has all of the relevant data, but if not then it hits a bunch of TypeErrors for null values.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am wondering if I should use `NoPioneer()` (which executes if the user is identified as not having the pioneer achievement) to populate empty values to the `playerData` object so that it at least doesn’t hit null references in the object.

Additionally, I have found if I remove the `playerData.settlement.settlementName` rendering reference (which is the data that may or may not exist depending on the player's pioneer status) the component renders. So, this makes me think that I may need to add a condition to the rendering call to check if the data exists (though sadly I am unsure of how to do this).

Here is my React component for reference:

```
function Dashboard() {
    const [ error, setError ] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();

    const pioneer_emails = Firebase.database().ref("pioneer_emails");
    const player_achievements = Firebase.database().ref("players/" + currentUser.uid + "/achievements");
    const [ pioneer, setPioneer ] = useState(false);
    const [ playerData, setPlayerData ] = useState({
        player_data: {
            playerName: "",
        },
        settlement: {
            settlementName: "",
        }
    });
    const playerName = playerData.player_data.playerName;
    const settlementName = playerData.settlement.settlementName;

    var dateVariable = Date().toLocaleString()

    async function CheckForPioneer(){
        //check if email is on pioneer list
        await pioneer_emails.on('value', gotEmail, errData);
        //if not, then check if the player has the achievement already
        if(!pioneer) {
            player_achievements.on('value', gotAchievement, noPioneer);
        }
    }

    //check to see if the player's email is on the pioneer list
    function gotEmail(data){
        //console.log(data.val())
        var emails = data.val();
        var keys = Object.keys(emails);

        for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            let k = keys[i];
            if(emails[k] === currentUser.email){
                //set bool
                setPioneer(true);
                //add achievement to database
                SetPioneerAchievement();
                //delete email from database
                pioneer_emails.child(k).remove();
            }
        }
    }

    //check to see if the player has the pioneer achievement
    function gotAchievement(data){
        var achievements = data.val();
        var achievementKeys = Object.keys(achievements);

        for(var i = 0; i < achievementKeys.length; i++){
            if(achievementKeys[i] === "MISC001"){
                setPioneer(true);
                console.log("We got a pioneer, baby!");
            }
        }
    }

    function noPioneer(){
        console.log('Player is not a pioneer!');
    }

    function errData(err){
        console.log('Error!');
        console.log(err)
    }

    function GetPlayerData(){
        Firebase.database().ref().child("players").child(currentUser.uid).get().then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            setPlayerData(snapshot.val());
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            console.log(playerData);
            console.log(playerData.player_data.playerName);         
            console.log(playerData.settlement.settlementName);
        } else {
            console.log("No data available");
        }
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        });
    }

    function SetPioneerAchievement(){
        const achievement = {
            "MISC001": {
                name: "Kickstarter Pioneer",
                completed: dateVariable
            }
        }
        player_achievements.set(achievement).catch(alert);
        console.log('Achievement added: ' + achievement.name)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        GetPlayerData();
        CheckForPioneer();
    }, []);

    return (
    <div className="dashboard">
        <div className="dashboard-box">
            <div className="dashboard-content">
                <h1>DASHBOARD</h1>
                <br /><alert>{error}</alert>
                <br />
                <center><h3>Name:</h3></center>
                <center><h2>Ancestor {playerData && playerData.player_data.playerName}</h2></center>
                <center>{pioneer ? <h3 className="pioneer-tag">Pioneer from the 2021 Kickstarter Campaign</h3> : null }</center>
                <br /><br />
                { pioneer ? (
                <div><center><h3>Founder of the:</h3></center>
                <center><h2>{playerData && playerData.settlement.settlementName} Settlement</h2></center></div>
                )
                : null }
                <center><Link to="/update-dashboard" className="link"><input type="submit" id="ancestor-signup-submit"  name="dashboard-update-details" value="Update Details" /></Link></center>
                <br />
                <div class="footer-switch-login">
                    <center><Link to="/" onClick={handleLogout} className="link">Log out.</Link></center>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your question/issue correctly, the code is essentially working as expected, but sometimes some users/data/state is incomplete. For this the solution is to use null-checks/guard-clauses or the [Optional Chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

You *sort* of already do this in a couple places:

```
playerData && playerData.player_data.playerName
```

and

```
playerData && playerData.settlement.settlementName
```

but you aren't checking at each depth of object property access.

1. Using null-checks/guard-clauses.

   ```
    playerData &&
    playerData.player_data &&
    playerData.player_data.playerName
   ```

   and

   ```
    playerData &&
    playerData.settlement &&
    playerData.settlement.settlementName
   ```
2. Using Optional Chaining operator

   ```
    playerData?.player_data?.playerName
   ```

   and

   ```
    playerData?.settlement?.settlementName
   ```

> I am wondering if I should use `NoPioneer()` (which executes if the user
> is identified as not having the pioneer achievement) to populate empty
> values to the `playerData` object so that it at least doesn’t hit null
> references in the object.

This sounds like a fantastic idea as it helps eliminate the chances of potentially accessing into null or undefined object properties.